# Can I have multiple Sybase (or any other) ODBC Drivers installed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, odbc

Is it possible to have two different version of an ODBC driver installed on a single server, specifically `Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise 12.5` and `Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5`?

Obviously any program would have to use one driver or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. With Sybase I can not guarantee as we only have 12.5 installed. But with the Oracle ODBC drivers this is absolutely no problem. We have all versions installed side by side from version 9 upto 11 (version 8 doesn't work because of ODBC issues).